# Do I have to provide an email for a local user on Windows 10 Pro?

Tags: windows-10, user-accounts

I'd like to create a user on Windows 10 that is just a username and a password, no email, no MS communication.

Reason?  No particular reason.  I don't feel like providing an email, or creating an email account.  None of Microsoft's business and I am quite comfortable with assuming the risks wrt to recovery in case a password is forgotten or the like.

Is this still possible?  I looked in Settings/Accounts/Family and other people.  Add a Family Member or Add someone else both seem stubborn in asking for an email, not just a user name.

I know there must be some way, for example I set up a MS SQL Server account in the past and it probably doesn't have an email. I just don't see any obvious way to do this in Settings/Accounts, which is where I expect this type of configuration to take place.

I have build 15063, Pro edition.

Comment: Linking your local account to a Microsoft Account is 100% optional.  However parental controls features in Windows 8+ do require it.  Majority of those features can be reproduced with group policies and third-party parental control software

Comment: Relevant: https://superuser.com/questions/1182304/simple-user-accounts-in-windows-10?rq=1 and https://superuser.com/questions/904673/can-i-install-windows-10-with-a-local-account and https://superuser.com/questions/1025565/what-happens-when-you-create-a-local-account-on-windows-10

Comment: I mentioned the parental controls due to how your adding a user because I have never created a user using that method

Comment: Agreed, the "family controls" are a whole different ball of wax, even if they create the same user.  This method will persist I suspect, but I wouldn't be so sure of any under the "parental controls".  Not saying they won't, just not sure I'd expect them to.

Comment: You can create a new local account, or you can also, of course, create a domain account. Personally, I'm a fan of domain accounts more than local accounts, but I would prefer a local account to a Microsoft account if a domain was not available

Answer (score 60, accepted):

It's possible (I have a couple non-domain users, good "insurance").

Process is pretty simple, once you've seen it once:

- Open Settings->Accounts
- Under "**Accounts**" -> click on "**Family and Other People**"
- Under "**Other People**" -> click on "**Add Someone Else to this PC**"
- The dialog changes, click on "**I don't have this person's sign-in information**"
- The dialog changes again, click on "**Add a user without a Microsoft Account**"
- Add the username/password credentials

That's it, you're done, the Setting page should take you back to "User Management(Family and other People)" now, and the non-domain account will be under the "Other People" section.

Existing [Microsoft KB here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/4026923/windows-create-a-local-user-or-administrator-account-in-windows-10).

Comment: the hops they make you take... Yes, it's possible but if you really really want to do it: search the internet (no, we are not making it intuitively), if not found ask a question, then follow the provided steps: under a bunch of options and dialog boxes you will finally find the command you want. Now: do you really want to do that? Still yes? Hmm.. we are doing something wrong. Let us go back to the drawing board.

Comment: @bolov - It's actually pretty intuitive once you get used to it.  It makes a lot more sense now then it did prior to moving everything under the "Add a new account" screen, and it's more in-line with how you do it in Android

Comment: @Taegost - Yep, my thinking as well, it wasn't so intuitive, because we were so usd to the "old method", but now the sequence seems like it fits where it should.  Someone mentioned the old MMC too, which is handy, if you want to use something more like you're used to...

Comment: I've up-voted this answer.  Tonight as well, I needed to set-up a new Windows 10 laptop.  In the past I've been able to Not need to use an email.  Tonight almost everything I tried, didn't succeed.  I'm posting my '_workaround_' below as a supplement, because it is now 2 years after this answer.

Answer (score 20):

Or you can just open up an elevated command prompt (or powershell shell) and add the user with the following command:

`net user <username> /add *`

for example:

`net user gizmo /add *`

and type the password twice, done.

If you want to make the user an Administrator too, subsequently use this command:

`net localgroup administrators <username> /add`

Then if you want to get rid of the user again use

`net user <username> /delete`

Answer (score 2):

Press Windows-R, or open a Command Prompt, and type:

```
mmc compmgmt.msc
```

and click OK/press return. This will open the Computer Management console and you can use this to manage local users.

Alternatively just run `mmc`, click File, Add/Remove snap-in and add the Local Users and Groups snap-in. This is the same snap-in available in the Computer Management console. You can save this console for future reuse if you think you're likely to need it again.

Answer (score 1):

#### Use the Local User and Groups snap-in

The Pro editions of Windows include the *Local Users and Groups* snap-in which provides a GUI method for adding (or changing) local accounts:

1. In Start, search and run `lusrmgr.msc`
2. Right-click *Users* in the left pane then click **New User...**

   [image]
3. Complete at least the 'User name' and both 'Password' fields, then click **Create**.
   Note: Also consider clearing the **User must change password at next logon** box

   [image]

The above steps create a standard user account. If you also wish to make the account a member of the Administrators group, do the following:

1. Click **Groups** in the left pane
2. In the right pane, right-click the group the user will be added to, such as **Administrators**, then click **Add to Group...**

   [image]
3. In the dialog box, click **Add...**
4. In the Select Users box, type the username then click **OK** twice

   [image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Windows 10 and set up a local user that isn't tied to a Microsoft account. On the screen where it asks you to either log in with a Microsoft account or create one there's a tiny "skip this step" button.

Answer (score 0):

Tonight, I needed to set-up a new Windows 10 laptop.  In the past I've been able to Not need to use an email.  Now Cortana just insisted that I provide:

- email address
- phone number

There is no explanation for this and while in the past it has been difficult to have a "**username**", this time it seemed that was not to be an option.

I found a workaround ... Do NOT connect the internet.

- During initial set-up you can skip the internet connection.
- Without an internet connection Cortana asks only for a username.
- The remainder of the install/set-up seems to work fine.

If you do set-up an internet connection, as I did first-off, turn off the PC and start again.  In my case, I was quite lucky because I was using a "metered connection" and I had set "Connect Automatically" to FALSE (empty check-box).

When I restarted, luckily the internet wasn't connected (by default) and I was able to skip that action.  Just move past the 'advise that things will go "better" with an internet connection.  Everything worked fine on the set-up for me.

When it came to setting-up a administrator/username I was NOT asked for an email or a phone, just a `username`.  Vanilla.

Personally, I can't see why having an email address for a login is important.  What happens when your email needs to change???  Yes, it can make sense to Keep an email for the log-in account.  That would be a fantastic help!  I was not asked such a question tonight.

This extra information comes, around 2 years after the best answer above.  For my example, this is how I got around the initial PC set-up username.